# ¿Como eliminar el último guión de un bucle?

Tags: php

Obtengo datos de una columna de una tabla que se van concatenando y separando mediante un guión. El problema es que genera un guión de más.

¿Cómo lo resuelvo?

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result2)) { 

    $codzona1= $row["codzona"]; 

    $codzona2 = $codzona2.$codzona1.'-';              
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías usar [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php).

Así por ejemplo:

```
$codzona1 = array();
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result2)) { 
     $codzona1[] = $row["codzona"];
}
$codzona2 = implode('-', $codzona1);
```

Comment: Esta es una mejor opción.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes conseguir sin usar **ninguna función** como han mencionado hasta ahora:

```
$array = ["toto", "titi", "tata", "tutu", "tete"];

$dash   = '';
$string = '';    

foreach ($array as $value) { 

    $string .= $dash.$value;    

    $dash = '-';
}

echo $string;

// Resultado => toto-titi-tata-tutu-tete
```

Este *simple script* recorre todo el array y deja de poner en la última vuelta el guión.

[**Ver Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/41d64aa982730d35b51a214df479654ae823f962)

Tu código usando esta técnica:

```
$dash   = '';  
$string = '';

while($row = pg_fetch_array($result2)) { 

    $string .= $dash.$row["codzona"]; 

    $dash = '-';            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recortando la última parte de la cadena generada, después del `while`:

```
$codzona2 = substr($codzona2, 0, strlen($codzona2)-1)
```

**EDITADO:**

Una versión más óptima sería la dicha por @MarcosGallardo:

```
$codzona2 = substr($codzona2, 0, -1);
```

Comment: gracias si funciono pero no en el mismo while si no fuera desde donde llamo el valor

Comment: Sí, es de hacerlo fuera del `while`

Comment: Podrías simplificarlo a `substr($codzona2, 0, -1);`

Comment: Esa no me la podía, gracias @MarcosGallardo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función [rtrim()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.rtrim.php) que retira los espacios en blanco (u otros caracteres) del final de un string.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  echo rtrim("codigo1-codigo2-", "-");
?>
```

Te devolverá:

```
codigo1-codigo2
```